# How to Pass PackagePassword into Execute of SSIS Package in SSMS

Tags: ssis, ssms

I am trying to execute a SSIS package with `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword` protection level from SSMS and getting the following error:

"The protection level of the package requires a password, but PackagePassword property is empty".

I then tried to set the property via the Advanced tab when executing the package and I get the following error instead:

"Failed to configure an overridden property that has the following path: PackagePassword. Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node because the password was not specified or not correct. Package load will attempt to continue without encrypted information."

[image]

How would I go about running a package that has that protection level from SSMS? It runs fine when in Visual Studio.

Comment: Usually that error means you've flubbed the password. Command line it would look like `dtexec /file C:\path\mypackage.dtsx /p MyPasswordIsSecure`  Script out the job step and see what command is being built relative to what it should be

Comment: @billinkc - reading up on it, it looks as though the `/p` parameter is used when it is guarded by SQL Server Authentication. I saw the `/De[crypt]` parameter would maybe be what I needed (`Sets the decryption password that is used when you load a package with password encryption.`), however I get the same error when using that from the command line.